# How can I clone my BitBucket repository to my web host using FTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, bitbucket, clone, bitbucket-server

I'm using GoDaddy and AWS I want to clone my BitBucket (2 accounts, one on each) repo to these hosts. How can I do that? I have FTP credentials for both.

Comment: can u give bit more detail on what u are trying to do here? how many repositories do u have? what is the issue? are u failing to clone a repo?

Comment: yes, I have many repositories on BitBucket and I want to clone them on my AWS server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a repository is a very straight forward thing. I suggest you research more.

Follow this guide on how to clone a repository from bitbucket [How to clone a repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html)